# Extracting rows from a pandas DataFrame based on records

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Suppose I have a dataframe as follows:

```
In [42]: df
Out[42]: 
      regiment company      name  preTestScore  postTestScore
0   Nighthawks     1st    Miller             4             25
1   Nighthawks     1st  Jacobson            24             94
2   Nighthawks     2nd       Ali            31             57
3   Nighthawks     2nd    Milner             2             62
4     Dragoons     1st     Cooze             3             70
5     Dragoons     1st     Jacon             4             25
6     Dragoons     2nd    Ryaner            24             94
7     Dragoons     2nd      Sone            31             57
8       Scouts     1st     Sloan             2             62
9       Scouts     1st     Piger             3             70
10      Scouts     2nd     Riani             2             62
11      Scouts     2nd       Ali             3             70
```

So what I did was:

I made a list of tuples as follows:

`In [48]: s = [('Nighthawks', '1st', 'Miller'), ('Scouts', '2nd', 'Ali')]`

and when I do `In [40]: df.loc[s]`

I get a KeyError

I was just trying to do random things, and was stuck here. Why I cannot extract rows based on info contained in tuples?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Just trying to extract the rows of DataFrame df which are same as in s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key error is because `loc` expects the index as the first argument. You're passing the entire record...? This isn't going to work.

This works:

```
print(df.loc[:4])
     regiment company      name  preTestScore  postTestScore
0  Nighthawks     1st    Miller             4             25
1  Nighthawks     1st  Jacobson            24             94
2  Nighthawks     2nd       Ali            31             57
3  Nighthawks     2nd    Milner             2             62
4    Dragoons     1st     Cooze             3             70
```

This doesn't:

```
print(df.loc[s[:4]])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-624-7f654aad4cfd> in <module>()
----> 1 df.loc[s[:4]]
```

Note that if you're trying to retrieve rows by their positional index, you're better off using `df.iloc`.

---

Addressing your comments, you should unzip them and use `df.isin`:

```
x, y, z = zip(*[('Nighthawks', '1st', 'Miller'), ('Dragoons', '2nd', 'Cooze')])
out = df[df.regiment.isin(x) & df.company.isin(y) & df.name.isin(z)]
print(out)
     regiment company    name  preTestScore  postTestScore
0  Nighthawks     1st  Miller             4             25
4    Dragoons     1st   Cooze             3             70
```

And, the inverse using the negation `~` operation:

```
out = df[~(df.regiment.isin(x) & df.company.isin(y) & df.name.isin(z))]
print(out)
      regiment company      name  preTestScore  postTestScore
1   Nighthawks     1st  Jacobson            24             94
2   Nighthawks     2nd       Ali            31             57
3   Nighthawks     2nd    Milner             2             62
5     Dragoons     1st     Jacon             4             25
6     Dragoons     2nd    Ryaner            24             94
7     Dragoons     2nd      Sone            31             57
8       Scouts     1st     Sloan             2             62
9       Scouts     1st     Piger             3             70
10      Scouts     2nd     Riani             2             62
11      Scouts     2nd       Ali             3             70
```

Comment: Ok, but what if I have a list of tuples like
s  = [('Nighthawks', '1st', 'Miller'), ('Dragoons', '2nd', 'Cooze')]
and I want to extract corresponding rows?

Comment: @coldspeed I am not able to figure this out
thats why plz help

Comment: @anonymous Look at my answer. I've addressed your question. If it works, do consider marking my answer accepted.

Comment: @coldspeed thanks it worked, last thing I want to ask is how will I fetch remaining dataframe that is not in the list of tuples?

Comment: @anonymous Edited. If you have any more questions, please open a new thread.